# Sticky header overlap content

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, sticky

I found answers for this question but it doesn't help my situation. This is my [site](https://kieferorthop%C3%A4die-dietze.de/praxis/#team/), when I jump to content, the header overlapped by sticky header.

This is my idea to fix it:

1. I will get #team from the link (e.g: [https://kieferorthopädie-dietze.de/praxis/#team/](https://kieferorthop%C3%A4die-dietze.de/praxis/#team/))
2. Then will compare the #team with container, if the container has the same id with link, I will add padding-top to the body.
3. If user scroll up, body will remove padding-top.

Hope anyone can give tell me how to code to fix this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share the code please. i am unable to open your website. You can use SO code or codepen

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Please provide code sample in the question instead of posting live sites link

Comment: @Chris please take a look my site, I already update link.

Comment: @TheHung, i can't see any menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in pure CSS - I do it myself on www.cntrl.no/license (click on one of the links in the index)

```
h4::before {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 7em;
    margin-top: -7em;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Granted, that is for the `h4` I use - you can of course substitute that for whatever container or element you use to jump to. And the height is for my header-bar height - you will probably have to adjust it slightly.

Comment: It should works when the user click on menu and jump to area instead of fixed styling.

Comment: It does...? I don't understand what you mean. Do you mean it should work with different elements (like you have one div with an id, and another heading with an id, and so on?)

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I wasn't explained clearly. Here I mean: If user clicks on menu, then it jump the area. Then, we will check if that area exist, body will add padding-top attribute, then it will remove it.

Comment: Yes...? And why would you do something so complicated in javascript, when a few lines of CSS can do it for you? That is exactly what the above code does, although it is based on `h4` being the element being jumped to. If you have other elements that you need to scroll to, just change the element.

Comment: Thanks you so much, it almost done. The title still hidden by header, could you please take a look my site http://prntscr.com/ddizm7

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a sticky header. Here is the code i wrote which might help you get started. I am assuming you will have more sections with content.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
    $('header').addClass("sticky");
  } else {
    $('header').removeClass("sticky");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header.sticky {
  background: #aaa;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 120px;
}

section {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

.container {
  width: 960px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <h1><a href="#link">Click Here</a></h1> </header>
<div class="container">
  <section class="content" >
 <p>askld f;a jsd;f jasld jf;la ;jsdlkfj ;asd jf;a jsd;lkf jalk;s df;l ;alk sdjf;lajsd fja;s dllf jalksdjf; jas;ldjf ;laj sd;flj a;lsj dfkl; jasdf jkaj s;df lkaj sd;kfj ak;lsd jf;lka jsd;lfj ;ajs dlkf ajskdjf ajs d;klfj aksldj</p>
   <p>askld f;a jsd;f jasld jf;la ;jsdlkfj ;asd jf;a jsd;lkf jalk;s df;l ;alk sdjf;lajsd fja;s dllf jalksdjf; jas;ldjf ;laj sd;flj a;lsj dfkl; jasdf jkaj s;df lkaj sd;kfj ak;lsd jf;lka jsd;lfj ;ajs dlkf ajskdjf ajs d;klfj aksldj</p>
   <p>askld f;a jsd;f jasld jf;la ;jsdlkfj ;asd jf;a jsd;lkf jalk;s df;l ;alk sdjf;lajsd fja;s dllf jalksdjf; jas;ldjf ;laj sd;flj a;lsj dfkl; jasdf jkaj s;df lkaj sd;kfj ak;lsd jf;lka jsd;lfj ;ajs dlkf ajskdjf ajs d;klfj aksldj</p>
   <p>askld f;a jsd;f jasld jf;la ;jsdlkfj ;asd jf;a jsd;lkf jalk;s df;l ;alk sdjf;lajsd fja;s dllf jalksdjf; jas;ldjf ;laj sd;flj a;lsj dfkl; jasdf jkaj s;df lkaj sd;kfj ak;lsd jf;lka jsd;lfj ;ajs dlkf ajskdjf ajs d;klfj aksldj</p>
   <p>askld f;a jsd;f jasld jf;la ;jsdlkfj ;asd jf;a jsd;lkf jalk;s df;l ;alk sdjf;lajsd fja;s dllf jalksdjf; jas;ldjf ;laj sd;flj a;lsj dfkl; jasdf jkaj s;df lkaj sd;kfj ak;lsd jf;lka jsd;lfj ;ajs dlkf ajskdjf ajs d;klfj aksldj</p>
  
</section>
<section id="link">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400.jpg" alt="Image" /></section>
</div>
```

Also on codepen: http://codepen.io/hunzaboy/pen/WoXRRL

Comment: Thanks you for the code. But I already have a sticky menu, my issue is that sticky header overlap my content. Please take this picture http://prntscr.com/ddiw0x

Comment: are you using any plugins for the sticky header?